# Efficient method to determine relative positions in a hierarchy of objects in a list

Tags: c#

I have a simple object hierarchy generated from an XML file, something like this:

```
interface IMyObject
{
  IList<IMyObject> Children {get;}
}
```

Expressed as XML it would look like this. I added an ID attribute just to give you an idea what the "index" of the object is, it does not actually exist in the source data.

```
<MyObject ID="1">
    <Children>
        <MyObject ID="2">
            <Children>
                <MyObject ID="3" />
                <MyObject ID="4" />
            </Children>
        </MyObject>
        <MyObject ID="5">
            <Children>
                <MyObject ID="6" />
                <MyObject ID="7" />
            </Children>
        </MyObject>
        <MyObject ID="8" />
    </Children>
</MyObject>
```

Now I need to check the relative order of n such objects from the hierarchy, i.e. I have three objects and need to check which comes first, second and third (using depth-first traversal)

My idea was to just flatten the list and get the index of each object and compare them which works exactly as I want:

```
public IList<IMyObject> GetFlattenedControlHierarchy()
{
    IList<IMyObject> Find(IEnumerable<IMyObject> controls)
    {
        return controls.Select(childControl =>
            {
                var currentLevel = new List<IMyObject>
                {
                    childControl
                };

                return currentLevel.Concat(Find(childControl.IMyObject));
            }
        ).SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
    }
    return Find(new[] { this });
}
```

However this strikes me as inefficient because I have to iterate the entire graph if I just want the index of a single control. `yield return` requires an IEnumerable which is unordered by definition so I can't use that here. Is there a way to short-circuit that or make it more efficient? The hierarchy is *relatively* small, usually up to 100 elements overall, but probably never larger than 300 or so.

Comment: (not an answer to your question, but ...) I'm not entirely sure you what you mean by "`yield return` requires an IEnumerable which is unordered by definition".

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, I think you can use the **Iterator pattern** here. You can traverse an object structure without knowing its internal details!

Comment: If this search is going to be performed often wouldn’t it be better to explicitly set the depth in the  object hierarchy itself; it would just be a simple property in `IMyObject` and easily and cheaply computed as you build the object tree.

Comment: How would you define relative order for siblings or cousins?

Comment: @AdamG It's determined by the index of the list in the `Children` list. Likewise for cousins, if a parent item comes before another, the children of the latter come after the children of the former.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen `yield return` would require me to return an IEnumerable which is not a sorted sequence.

Comment: "yield return requires an IEnumerable which is unordered by definition" On the contrary - an `IEnumerable` is an ordered sequence - iterating an `IEnumerable` is done using a `foreach` loop, which internally is using the `MoveNext()` method of the `IEnumerator` - so clearly it is ordered...

Comment: BTW what you have is a tree structure - each parent might have multiple children - so it's entirely possible all objects you are searching for are on the same level (counting from the root element).

Comment: I am confused about the data structure. Is it a graph, tree, or list? If it's not a list, how are the ordinal numbers computed? Is there a root? If it's to be treated as a ruleless network then there are considerable edge cases you are failing to account for, such as cycles.

Comment: Extending it further, does the great great grandchild of the first child of the root come before the second child of the root?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question a bit. It's basically a tree with ordered nodes. Cycles are not possible, each children has exactly one parent and can have 0..n children.